# SQL WHERE excluding records using AND and NOT

Tags: sql, syntax

Here's a query I'm working on:

```
SELECT  TBL_SUB_KEY AS port
      , poe.[TBL_COMPANY]
      , poe.[TBL_DIVISION_1]
FROM    dbo.TMVKTAB AS poe
WHERE   ( TBL_NUMBER = '8A' )
        AND ( TBL_SUB_KEY <> '' )
        AND ( poe.[TBL_COMPANY] <> '011'
              AND poe.[TBL_DIVISION_1] <> '11'
            )
```

What I want returned are all the records that are **not** in Company = '011'/Division_1' = '11'.

I thought combining the company/division in the () would achieve this, but it does not. It eliminates all the company '011' records and it eliminates all division '11' records.

However, when I do this:

```
SELECT  TBL_SUB_KEY AS port
      , poe.[TBL_COMPANY]
      , poe.[TBL_DIVISION_1]
FROM    dbo.TMVKTAB AS poe
WHERE   ( TBL_NUMBER = '8A' )
        AND ( TBL_SUB_KEY <> '' )
        AND NOT ( poe.[TBL_COMPANY] = '011'
              AND poe.[TBL_DIVISION_1] = '11'
            )
```

it seems to pull the correct results. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a boolean logic issue:

```
NOT (A and B) <=> NOT A  OR NOT B
```

i.e.:

```
NOT ( poe.[TBL_COMPANY] = '011' AND poe.[TBL_DIVISION_1] = '11')
```

Is equivalent to:

```
( poe.[TBL_COMPANY] <> '011' OR poe.[TBL_DIVISION_1] <> '11')
```

Read:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic

Comment: Doh! I tried the OR, and I *thought* I was getting incorrect results. Tried it again and you are correct.

Comment: As long as neither TBL_COMPANY nor TBL_DIVISION can be NULL, this is fine.  If either can store NULL, then the condition has to be much more complex: ((poe.TBL_COMPANY <> '011' OR poe.TBL_COMPANY IS NULL) OR (poe.TBL_DIVISION <> '11' OR poe.TBL_DIVISION IS NULL)).  3VL is so much fun.

Answer (score 3):

I think the equivalent to the NOT would use OR as shown below:

```
SELECT  TBL_SUB_KEY AS port
      , poe.[TBL_COMPANY]
      , poe.[TBL_DIVISION_1]
FROM    dbo.TMVKTAB AS poe
WHERE   ( TBL_NUMBER = '8A' )
        AND ( TBL_SUB_KEY <> '' )
        AND ( poe.[TBL_COMPANY] <> '011'
              OR poe.[TBL_DIVISION_1] <> '11'
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
where x and (y and z)
```

is the same as

```
x and y and z
```

however

```
where x and not (y and z)
```

is what you want, and works.

try this:

```
SELECT  TBL_SUB_KEY AS port
      , poe.[TBL_COMPANY]
      , poe.[TBL_DIVISION_1]
FROM    dbo.TMVKTAB AS poe
WHERE   ( TBL_NUMBER = '8A' )
        AND ( TBL_SUB_KEY <> '' )
        AND NOT ( poe.[TBL_COMPANY] = '011'
                  AND poe.[TBL_DIVISION_1] = '11'
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

Time for some boolean algebra. This:

```
not (x and y)
```

is the same as:

```
(not x or not y)
```

So your query should be:

```
SELECT  TBL_SUB_KEY AS port
      , poe.[TBL_COMPANY]
      , poe.[TBL_DIVISION_1]
FROM    dbo.TMVKTAB AS poe
WHERE   ( TBL_NUMBER = '8A' )
        AND ( TBL_SUB_KEY <> '' )
        AND ( poe.[TBL_COMPANY] <> '011'
              OR poe.[TBL_DIVISION_1] <> '11'
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Because records not belonging to **both** Company 011 and Division 11 are matched by

```
          poe.[TBL_COMPANY] <> '011'
          OR poe.[TBL_DIVISION_1] <> '11'
```

If company is not 011, division can be 11 and you'll still have a matching combination.

[De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) explains how to convert boolean expressions in such a manner.